# How to display list of elements from database in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

So,i have a database(SqlServer) and a table that contain a columns(**firstname,lastname,picture**), and i want when i press a button to get the list of my elements (Like the **user control** in **WPF**), in other words i want to display each image with first and last name.
So please if someone have any idea i will be very appreciate.

i need something look like:
[enter link description here](http://www.mediafire.com/view/?u8he3l5huk86nj6)

Comment: That's a very broad question. What type of database (let's say) connectivity do you use? ADO .NET, EF, NHibernate?

Comment: There are lot of options - DataGridView, UserControl + FlowLayoutPanel, DataRepater (VB.Net)

Comment: I use ADO.NET, any help !

Comment: @Mohammadov Please flesh out the question a bit. Do you want to display whole records, only selected columns, should it be a grid, listbox, some kind of custom control?

Comment: It might be useful to start from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/keb37h7b.aspx But this is just as generic as your question and might not even answer it.

Comment: i need something like that http://www.mediafire.com/view/?u8he3l5huk86nj6

Comment: This doesn't seem to be much of a question.  More of "help me, do this project for me!"  Can you please get a little more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking how to get a picture from SQL Server database, you should check the following link:

http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_read_write_blob.html

It also shows how to dsiplay it via PictureBox control in WinForms.

If you are asking how to dynamically create controls in winforms, try this:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319266

Hope it helps,

Comment: thanks Pawel that what i am looking for (dynamically create controls in winforms)